# Get additional data around match from grep

Tags: grep

I'm wondering how to improve my `grep` use when being confronted with files with very long lines. Imagine something like "packed" JavaScript files that only have 1 line. Sometimes files like that spit out results which I didn't expect and flood my console (especially when using `--recursive`).

I guess I would like something like `--context` but for words/bytes around the match. I thought I was being smart by coming up with this usage:

```
$ grep -rino --color ".\{0,20\}something.\{0,20\}" *
```

But that makes the characters around my search term part of the match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess a solution was somewhat in front of my face. I'm now using this function in my `.bashrc`:

```
grepAdjusted()
{
  grep -Erino ".{0,20}$1.{0,20}" ${@:2:$(($#-1))} | grep -i --color "$1"
}
alias g=grepAdjusted
```

I kept it simple and to my most common use case. It's not a perfect answer to my original question, but it provides what I was looking for.

[image: Output of grepAdjusted]