# How can I retain grep's match highlighting when piping find into grep?

Tags: terminal, find, grep, pipe, highlighting

If I run `grep foo bar.txt`, grep highlights each occurrence of "foo" in `bar.txt`. But sometimes I want to use `find` to determine which files grep searches. So I do something like this:

```
find . -iname "*.abc" | xargs grep foo
```

Or this:

```
find . -iname "*.abc" -exec grep foo {} \;
```

In both cases, grep correctly finds occurrences of "foo" in the specified files, but the output has no highlighting whatsoever.

How can I keep using `find` to choose files for grep to search without losing highlighting?

I am running Gnome Terminal 3.4.1.1 on Ubuntu 12.04, with bash as my shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both commands, the problem is that not `grep` but another command generates the actual output (`xargs` and `find`, respectively).

You can solve this by directly calling `grep` for each file name:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for FILE in $(find . -iname "*.abc"); do
    grep foo $FILE
done
unset IFS
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
IFS=$'\n';for FILE in $(find . -iname "*.abc");do grep foo $FILE;done;unset IFS
```

#### How it works:

- `IFS=$'\n'` sets the internal field separator to the newline character (or spaces in file names will cause problems).
- `for FILE in $(COMMAND); do COMMANDS done` loops through the files specified by `COMMAND`, sets the variable `FILE` to the current file and executes `COMMANDS`.
- `grep foo $FILE` searches for `foo` in `$FILE` and sends the results **directly** to the screen.
- `unset IFS` sets the internal field separator back to its default value (not needed in a script).

Answer (score 3):

Just `grep` your output again to color it.

I did something similar here: [Get additional data around match from grep](https://superuser.com/questions/368339/get-additional-data-around-match-from-grep)

Comment: Well, that's much easier than my approach. Adjusted syntax to use `grep` only once and allow spaces in file names: `find . -iname "*.abc" -print0 | xargs -0 cat | grep foo`